# AX=B,calculate complex matrix,while A and B is many dimensions

Tags: jaxb2-basics

now I  calculate AX=B  ,while A X B  is complex  matrix,if i set size A is 3*3，B  is 3*1，and it  Calculate the correct.But if i set A is 58*58 and B is 58*256 complex matrix,it Calculation error.And i see the error  happen at  cublasCgemv,.I see the L have value,and d_B have value also,after  cublasCgemv,there is no value ,

Comment: I want to konw whether cublasCgemv  is only  Calculate the Unknown matrices size is n*1 matrices

Comment: Now I has been solved